# How to stop dotnet run command?

Tags: terminal, applescript, script

I have written a script to build and run my dotnet project but it seems I am not able to stop it. The code I wrote is below.

```
do shell script "eval $(/usr/libexec/path_helper -s)
cd /Users/Projects/sth.api
dotnet run &"
```

Upon triggering this script from Script Editor, I am not able to stop it again. I don't want my project to run all the time. Now I need to open Activity Monitor and find the dotnet application which is also impossible so I have to stop all dotnet projects.

I have exported script as Application, and clicked Show Startup Screen and Stay Open After Run Handler.
That opens a dialog with Run and Quit buttons. I want to stop the dotnet project when I clicked the Quit button.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the *&* character from the command. That character makes the command run in the background - i.e. the script completes right away even though your .NET program is still running.